# How to check if startActivity is Allowed in background (Android)?

Tags: android, start-activity

When notification is received Activity can not be launched due to background restrictions in android

How to check i am allowed to call startActivity through code without try catch block
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Answer (score -1):

Use PackageManager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourTargetActivity.class);

// Check if there is at least one activity that can handle the intent packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (!activities.isEmpty()) {
    // There's at least one activity that can handle this intent, so it's safe to start it
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // No activity can handle the intent, handle this case as needed (e.g., show an error message)
}
```